# Electron app crashes immediately after starting

Tags: go, ubuntu, electron-builder, electron-packager

I am trying to run a simple electron app created using go-astilectron (golang) on ubuntu. But the app crash immediately after starting with error given below.
And also its not reading the "index.html".
Stderr says:

> [4355:0928/181138.270381:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(445)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
> '/tmp/go-build14577/b001/exe/vendor/electron-linux-amd64/electron' exited with code: -1

```
func main() {
    demologger := log.New(log.Writer(), log.Prefix(), log.Flags())
    astiApp, apperror := astilectron.New(demologger, astilectron.Options{
        AppName: "demo",
    })
    if apperror != nil {
        fmt.Printf("main: creating the astilectron is failed: %w", apperror)
        panic(apperror)
    }
    defer astiApp.Close()
    astiApp.HandleSignals()

    if apperror = astiApp.Start(); apperror != nil {
        fmt.Printf("main: starting the astilectron is failed: %w", apperror)
        panic(apperror)
    }

    var win *astilectron.Window
    win, apperror = astiApp.NewWindow("index.html", &astilectron.WindowOptions{
        Center:      astikit.BoolPtr(true),
        Height:      astikit.IntPtr(250),
        Width:       astikit.IntPtr(400),
    })
    apperror = win.Create()
        astiApp.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Its only crashing in linux virtual machines And work good on physical machine.